# Proving $\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\tan{x}=\infty$, using $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, epsilon-delta

I would like to prove the following:
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2^-}\tan{x}=\infty$$
By the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, for any constant $K\in \Bbb{R}$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in(\pi/2-\delta,\pi/2)$ then $\tan(x)>K$. What I did was: 
$$x>\arctan{K}$$
Also, we know that $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}-\pi/2< \arctan{x}<\pi/2$, but I can't find out, how to choose the $\delta$. Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\delta=\frac\pi2-\arctan K$. Then,$$x\in\left(\frac\pi2-\delta,\frac\pi2\right)\iff\arctan K<x<\frac\pi2\implies\tan x>K.$$

Comment: Can i actually assume that $-\arctan{K}\geq -\pi/2$? Because in that case i would have $\delta=\pi/2-\arctan{K}\geq\pi/2-\pi/2=0$ therefore $\delta$ possibly being zero, which wouldn't be allowed? I'm wondering, whether $\arctan$ shouldn't be stricly lesser respectively greater than $\pi/2$ respectively $-\pi/2$

Comment: @MichalDvořák The range of $\arctan$ is $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But how could you say, $$\arctan K<x<\frac\pi2\implies\tan x>K$$ ? Sorry, if I sound stupid.

Comment: @ThomasFinley Since the restriction of the tangent function to $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ is strictly increasing, and since $\arctan K,x\in\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$,$$\arctan K<x\implies\tan\left(\arctan K\right)<\tan x\iff K<\tan x.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks a ton! I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and since $\sin(\pi/2)=1$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $\sin x>1/2$, for $\pi/2-\delta_1<x<\pi/2$.

Also $\cos(\pi/2)=0$ and the cosine is positive over $(0,\pi/2)$, so for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that, for $\pi/2-\delta_2<x<\pi/2$, $\cos x<\varepsilon$.

Given $M>0$ you want to find $\delta>0$ so that, for $\pi/2-\delta<x<\pi/2$,
$$
\tan x>M
$$
Choose $\delta_2$ such that, for $\pi/2-\delta_2<x<\pi/2$, $\cos x<1/(2M)$.

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. Then, for $\pi/2-\delta<x<\pi/2$, you have
$$
\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}>\frac{1}{2}2M=M
$$

Comment: In the third paragraph, isn't it $x<π/2$ ?? Otherwise nice proof, thanks.

Comment: @manud99 Yes, sure!